# How to validate Date in form onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

```
  function validatedate(inputText) { 
    var thsid = $(inputText).attr('id');
    var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-]\d{4}$/; 
  }
```

This is my common js method [incomplete] `onblur="validatedate(this)"` but its accepting invalid dates also

I have one datepicker in my jsp as `textbox.onblur` i need to validate date using javascript

> these are the rules

1. mm/dd/yy format
2. mm should not exceed 31
3. dd should not exceed 12
4. should be commom method for all datepickers
5. if given input invalid ..should give an alert and empty datepicker..............

Comment: input type date datetime?

Comment: @FUserThrowError : Only date : mm/dd/yy format

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
onblur="validatedate(this)"
```

To:

```
onblur="validatedate(this.value);"
```

`this` contains input DOM element itself and not the input's text value.

**Also** your `validatedate()` function appears to be doing nothing. There is no return value, no alert or anything to stop form processing. I take for granted you only supplied a snippet of the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Saidesh's answer got me most of the way to where I wanted, but I didn't like the JQuery dependency. I added a couple minor improvements as well as a fully functional test page.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">

function validatedate(inputTextObject) {
    // matches 11/12/2011 or 11-12-2011
    var ret = true;
    var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
    // Match the date format through regular expression  
    if (inputTextObject.value.trim() != "") {
        if (inputTextObject.value.trim().match(dateformat)) {
            // document.form1.text1.focus();  
            //Test which seperator is used '/' or '-'  
            var opera1 = inputTextObject.value.split('/');
            var opera2 = inputTextObject.value.split('-');
            lopera1 = opera1.length;
            lopera2 = opera2.length;
            // Extract the string into month, date and year  
            if (lopera1 > 1) {
                var pdate = inputTextObject.value.split('/');
            } else if (lopera2 > 1) {
                var pdate = inputTextObject.value.split('-');
            }
            var mm = parseInt(pdate[0]);
            var dd = parseInt(pdate[1]);
            var yy = parseInt(pdate[2]);
            // Create list of days of a month [assume there is a leap year by default]  
            var ListofDays = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
            if (mm == 1 || mm > 2) {
                if (dd > ListofDays[mm - 1]) {
                    alert('Invalid date format!');
                    inputTextObject.focus();
                    ret = false;
                }
            }
            if (mm == 2) {
                var lyear = false;
                if ((!(yy % 4) && yy % 100) || !(yy % 400)) {
                    lyear = true;
                }
                if ((lyear == false) && (dd >= 29)) {
                    alert('Invalid date format!');
                    inputTextObject.focus();
                    ret = false;
                }
                if ((lyear == true) && (dd > 29)) {
                    alert('Invalid date format!');
                    inputTextObject.focus();
                    ret = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Invalid date format!");
            inputTextObject.focus();
            ret = false;
        }

        if (ret == false) {
         inputTextObject.style.color='red';
        } else {
         inputTextObject.style.color='blue';
        }
        
    }
    return ret;

}
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
Date Test (<strong>mm/dd/yyyy</strong>): <input name="date_test" type="text" onblur="validatedate(this);" />
<img  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACYAAAAmAQMAAACS83vtAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAApElEQVQI1y3OQWpCMQBF0ZtnqF8Q286FCm7CgdgsqUv44qBuqvKXEqgLiCIokuY5qGcFJxiwcABxJoEHXhseedTkKQeony5NNdH1FLtuFEDofPc2i2sbeh0hl0jZgzoiKw1vPQhYICZKiJfQI4CFSFyyDA2FjFCCgm5fHLvIjWGs+Zo94fdvvnScOW74/6jbfdf0XClz4rnl530KLnw0XHELBvwAwg1K5dfpv8IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now my method is ready..with the help of stackoverflow:**

```
  function validatedate(inputText)  
{ 
var thsid=$(inputText).attr('id');
var classname=$(inputText).attr('class');
   var classstr=classname.split(" ");
var ret=true;
var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;  
// Match the date format through regular expression  
if(inputText.value.trim()!="")
{
if( inputText.value.trim().match(dateformat))  
 {  
  // document.form1.text1.focus();  
   //Test which seperator is used '/' or '-'  
   var opera1 = inputText.value.split('/');  
   var opera2 = inputText.value.split('-');  
  lopera1 = opera1.length;  
 lopera2 = opera2.length;  
  // Extract the string into month, date and year  
   if (lopera1>1)  
    {  
  var pdate = inputText.value.split('/');  
  }  
  else if (lopera2>1)  
  {  
  var pdate = inputText.value.split('-');  
  }  
 var mm  = parseInt(pdate[0]);  
 var dd = parseInt(pdate[1]);  
 var yy = parseInt(pdate[2]);  
  // Create list of days of a month [assume there is no leap year by default]  
   var ListofDays = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];  
  if (mm==1 || mm>2)  
  {  
  if (dd>ListofDays[mm-1])  
  {  
  alert('Invalid date format!');
 $(inputText).focus();
  inputText.value="";
   ret=false;
  return false;  
  }  
 }  
 if (mm==2)  
  {  
 var lyear = false;  
 if ( (!(yy % 4) && yy % 100) || !(yy % 400))   
  {  
 lyear = true;  
 }  
 if ((lyear==false) && (dd>=29))  
  {  
  alert('Invalid date format!'); 
  $('#'+thsid).focus();
   inputText.value="";
   ret=false;
  return false;  
 }  
 if ((lyear==true) && (dd>29))  
 {  
 alert('Invalid date format!');  
         $('#'+thsid).focus();
 inputText.value="";
  ret=false;
   return false;  
 }  
  }  
  }  
  else  
   {  
   alert("Invalid date format!");  
    $('#'+thsid).focus();
 inputText.value="";
    ret=false;
  return false;  
       }
 }
```